# !unzip is not recognize as command in jupyter cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

What should I do? Some suggest installing GNUWIN32?

[image]

Comment: `!magic` commands are not Python, they're iPython/jupyter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That cell is intended to be ran in a Unix environment, not Windows, based on usage of `/tmp`, `~`, in addition to `unzip`

Besides, python has native unzip functions, so ideally that should be rewritten

https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall

You could try gnuwin32, but that seems excessive and doesn't guarantee the rest of the notebook would run successfully

Comment: hi thank you for suggestion please could you write commands for me please

Comment: I don't think I can, considering I don't know what output you're expecting

Comment: You could alternatively just download the file yourself, extract it yourself, then continue on with the notebook. No sense in automating everything

Comment: Thank you sir for suggestion you are right we can unzip file manully